# Input parameters from a nested class to Pytorch Optimization Function

Tags: python, oop, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch

I have the following Graph neural network model and I am not able to get the learnable parameters of the model to do optimization.

```
from torch.nn.parameter import Parameter
from torch.nn.modules.module import Module
class Graphconvlayer(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,adj,input_feature_neurons,output_neurons):
    super(Graphconvlayer, self).__init__()
    self.adj=adj
    self.input_feature_neurons=input_feature_neurons
    self.output_neurons=output_neurons
    self.weights=Parameter(torch.normal(mean=0.0,std=torch.ones(input_feature_neurons,output_neurons)))
    self.bias=Parameter(torch.normal(mean=0.0,std=torch.ones(output_neurons)))
  
  def forward(self,inputfeaturedata):
    output1= torch.mm(self.adj,inputfeaturedata)
    print(output1.shape)
    print(self.weights.shape)
    print(self.bias.shape)
    output2= torch.matmul(output1,self.weights)+ self.bias
    return output2 

class GCN(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self,adj,input_feature_neurons,output_neurons,lr,dropoutvalue,hidden,data):
     super(GCN, self).__init__()
     self.adj=adj
     self.input_feature_neurons=input_feature_neurons
     self.output_neurons=output_neurons
     self.lr=lr
     self.dropoutvalue=dropoutvalue
     self.hidden=hidden
     self.data=data
     self.gcn1 = Graphconvlayer(adj,input_feature_neurons,hidden)
     self.gcn2 = Graphconvlayer(adj,hidden,output_neurons)
  
   def forward(self,x):
     x= F.relu(self.gcn1(x))
     x= F.dropout(x,self.dropoutvalue)
     x= self.gcn2(x)
     print("opop")
     return F.log_softmax(x,dim=1)
```

```
for n, p in a.named_parameters():
    print(n, p.shape)

>>>
gcn1.weights torch.Size([1433, 2708])
gcn1.bias torch.Size([2708])
gcn2.weights torch.Size([2708, 7])
gcn2.bias torch.Size([7])
>>>

optimizer= optim.Adam(a.named_parameters()),lr=0.001)
>>>
NameError: name 'optim' is not defined
```

When I pass it as a dict(a.named_parameters()), I am able to print the values, but can not pass it to the optimization function. Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: why not just use `parameters()`

Comment: Throwing the same error

Comment: could it be you just forgot to import `optim`?
`from torch import optim`